# SAS macro to create variable ratios

Tags: sas, sas-macro

I am trying to create a SAS macro that I can call for calculating ratio of variables. Here is how I have defined the ratio and used in a SAS dataset. I am getting error. What I am doing wrong? Thanks.

```
%macro ratio(num, den, ratio);
%if &den = . %then &ratio = -999999;
%else %if &den = 0 %then &ratio = -999998;
%else %if &num = . %then &ratio = -999997;
%else &ratio = &num/&den;
%mend ratio; 

data model_data;
set mysas.model_data;
 call %ratio(var1,var2,ratio_var1_to_var2);
run;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To explain the purpose of the Macro language:  SAS Macro is (mostly) used to create SAS Code  (it writes text).  This SAS Code is then *subsequently* executed, eg to perform calculations.

So in this case we need to use the macro to write the datastep (SAS) code - "if / then", not "%if / %then".

Try:

```
options mprint;
%macro ratio(num, den, ratio);
   if &den = . then &ratio = -999999;
   else if &den = 0 then &ratio = -999998;
   else if &num = . then &ratio = -999997;
   else &ratio = &num/&den;
%mend ratio; 

data model_data;
set mysas.model_data;
   %ratio(var1,var2,ratio_var1_to_var2)
run;
```

I've added the `options mprint` so you can see the result of the macro execution in your log..